# Protractor Promise callbacks not showing content. How do I call the methods of the returned item?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

In code below, when debugger is hit, the value of thing/item shows nothing (See image)..

```
it('CheckAllLinks:', function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser
        .findElements(by.tagName('a'))
        .then(function (items) {
           items.forEach(function (item) {
              var thing = item;
              debugger;
        });
    });
 });
```

For example any call to these methods only returns three dots using the immediate window in Visual Studio.  (...);
[image]

I realize this is a promise, but don't understand how to use any of the methods to validate content and click the link as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to be related to the fact that these calls themseleves are promises.  Promises are fulfilled when the .then statement is hit.  In example below there are two things being promised, the text and the href of each link.

```
it('CheckAllLinks:', function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser
        .findElements(by.tagName('a'))
        .then(function (items) {
        items.forEach(function (item, i) {
            var test = item.getText().then(function (text) {
                item.getAttribute('href').then(function (href) {
                    debugger;
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```